# One message limit AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am making chat application with AJAX and PHP MyAdminServer.

Here is my AJAX request:

```
function sendMessage() {
    const message = messageInput.val();
    if (message === "") return;
    let url = new URL(window.location.href);
    let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
    let IdFrom = params.get("IdFrom");
    let IdTo = params.get("IdTo");
    
    // creating new url
    let urlParts = url.href.split('/');
    urlParts.pop();
    urlParts.pop();
    urlParts.push("Chat");
    urlParts.push("acceptMessage");
    let newUrl = urlParts.join('/');  
    
    $.ajax({
      url: newUrl,
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        message: message,
        from: IdFrom,
        to: IdTo,
      },
      success: function (response) {
        // Assume the server responds with the sent message echoed back
        appendMessage("Server", response);
        messageInput.val(""); // Clear the input field
        messageInput.focus(); // Set focus back to the input field
      },
      error: function (error) {
        // Handle the error, if any
        console.log("Error:", error);
      },
    });    
    return false;
  }
```

I am sure that I called right controller and right method (Chat/acceptMessage which call insert function from PorukaModel). This code works properly only once and after that it does not allow me to insert new message, additionally I will leave my Model script:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

/**
 * PorukaModel - klasa za implementaciju funkcionalnosti za koriscenje tabele iz baze podataka
 * 
 * @version 1.0
 */
class PorukaModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * var String $table
     */
    protected $table      = "poruka";
    /**
     * var String $primaryKey
     */
    protected $primaryKey = "IdP";
    /**
     * var String $returnType
     */
    protected $returnType     = "object";
    /**
     * var Array $allowedFields
     */
    protected $allowedFields = ["Tekst", "DatumVreme", "IdPri", "IdPos"];

    public function insertData($IdFrom, $IdTo, $message)
    {
        $data = array(
            'IdPri' => $IdTo,
            'IdPos' => $IdFrom,
            'Tekst' => $message,
            'DatumVreme' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        );
        $this->insert($data, true); // true for auto validation
    }

}

?>
```

When I try to send another message my browser do not recognize this request as AJAX, and uses GET method insted of POST (but first time when database is empty, or when database has one element which I manually delete it is working properly).

Here is my controller class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\PorukaModel;

class Chat extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Prikaz pocetne stranice korisnika
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function showChatting()
    {
        $this->show("cetovanje", []);
    }

    // da li treba synchronized
    public function acceptMessage(){
        $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : null;
        $IdTo = isset($_POST['from']) ? intval($_POST['from']) : null;
        $IdFrom = isset($_POST['to']) ? intval($_POST['to']) : null;
        $PorukaModel = new PorukaModel(); 
        $PorukaModel->insertData($IdFrom, $IdTo, $message);

        // $response = "Message received: ".$message;
        // echo $response;
    }
}

?>
```